# How do I include a HTML file in a Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask micro-framework for my server which uses Jinja templates.

I have a parent `template.html` and some children templates called `child1.html` and `child2.html`, some of these children templates are pretty large HTML files and I would like to somehow split them for better lucidity over my work.

Contents of my `main.py` script:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<task>')
def home(task=''):
  return render_template('child1.html', task=task)

app.run()
```

The simplified `template.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The magic is in `child1.html`:

```
{% extends 'template.html' %}
{% block content %}
  {% if task == 'content1' %}
    <!-- include content1.html -->
  {% endif %}
  {% if task == 'content2' %}
    <!-- include content2.html -->
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Instead of the comments:

```
<!-- include content1.html -->
```

I have a lot of html text, and it is very hard to keep track of changes and not to make some mistakes, which are then pretty hard to find and correct.

I'd like to just load the `content1.html` instead of writing it all in `child1.html`.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file), but I had problems implementing it.

I think Jinja2 might have a better tool for that.

**NOTE:** The code above might not be working properly, I just wrote it to illustrate the problem.

Comment: What should I replace the 'content1'? I replaced it with the name of the file without extension. if that is right, then it is not working. I tried to encapsulate two html files in a list [% include ['content1.html, content2.html ]', but this too is not working only it takes the first, which is very obvious. Any idea?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Use the jinja2 [`{% include %}`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) directive.

```
{% extends 'template.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% if task == 'content1' %}
        {% include 'content1.html' %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if task == 'content2' %}
        {% include 'content2.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This will include the content from the correct content-file.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the [include](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) statement.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add the proper syntax for using include, one given above works fine, but when it comes to the path, it took some time to find this, it is not even mentioned in the official document.

Syntax for include is:

```
{% include 'path_to_template_file' %}
```